Calling a schedule on a function in Laravel console.php
I want to call a function in console.php as a schedule.
Here is my console.php code:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuctionController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schedule;

Schedule::call(function () {
    ([AuctionController::class, 'endAuction']);
    echo 'Zakończono aukcję.';
})->everyTenSeconds();

Here is my function code:
public function endAuction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $auction = Auction::findOrFail($id);

        DB::transaction(function () use ($auction) {
            if ($auction->bids()->count() == 0) {
                $maxQueue = Auction::max('queue');
                $deletedQueueValue = $auction->queue;

                $auction->update(['queue' => $maxQueue + 1]);

                $this->rindexAuctionQueue($deletedQueueValue);
            } else {
                $auction->update(['status' => 'ended']);

                if ($auction->currentBid) {
                    $auction->car->update([
                        'owner_id' => $auction->currentBid->user_id,
                        'status' => 'sold',
                        'price' => $auction->current_price
                    ]);
                }

                $deletedQueueValue = $auction->queue;

                $auction->delete();

                $this->rindexAuctionQueue($deletedQueueValue);

            }
        });

        return redirect()->route('mainpage')->with('success', 'Aukcja została zakończona.');
    }

Scheduler works, theres a echo in terminal which is printing for every 10 seconds, but the function is not calling. Any help? THANKS!

You're not sending the params to the endAuction, are you?

You tagged this with laravel-5 but sub-minute scheduled tasks seem to require laravel 10+

it's generally not best practice to call controller methods directly from a console command. Instead, it's better to encapsulate your business logic within a service class. This way, you can easily reuse the logic in both your controller and console command.
Additionally, your endAuction function requires an ID and other context, we need to pass these appropriately.
Encapsulate the endAuction logic within a service class. Refactor the controller to use the service class and call the service class in your schedule.

Even if I change the function to be without the any parameters, and change the scheduler to be used as a Job there is still no function at all.

You need to instantiate controller and call its method
||
$auctionController = new AuctionController();
$auctionController->endAuction($request, $id);

where would $request be coming from in the console?

The reason your controller function executing is because you never called it. The line ([AuctionController::class, 'endAuction']); in your closure doesn't call a function. All it does is create an array that looks something like
['app/Http/Controllers/AuctionController', 'endAuction']

So when your scheduled closure is called every ten seconds, it makes this array (doesn't do anything with it), echo's out the statement and exits.
As is mentioned in the comments, controller classes are used specifically for route logic. You're better of making this into a console command, which can be scheduled easily. Then even if you did need to run this from a route, you can trigger the command progrommatically.
However, the quick and dirty way to get your code to run would to be to initiate the AuctionController class and call the endAuction method on it. First you would need to refactor the function signature to no longer use the request. Then you could pass the ID as the first parameter.
public function endAuction($id){
    ...
}

<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuctionController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schedule;

Schedule::call(function () {
    $id = 1 //Not sure how you would figure this out but commands would let you pass this in as a parameter

    $controller = new AuctionController();
    $controller->endAuction($id);
})->everyTenSeconds();

